# Python - How to print one backslash in a string within a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a dictionary with some strings, in one of the string there are two backslashes. I want to replace them with a single backslash.

These are the backslashes: **IfNotExist\\u003dtrue**

```
Configurations = {
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName": "test",
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName": "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver",
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword": "sxxxsasdsasad",
        "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": "jdbc:mysql://hive-metastore.cr.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist\\u003dtrue"

}
print (Configurations)
```

When I print it keeps showing the two backslashes. I know that the way to escape a backslash is using \ this works in a regular string but it does not work in a dictionary.

Any ideas?

Comment: why should it not work? looks like a valid value for me

Comment: You need to tell us the actual code you are executing. What does your print statement look like?

Comment: how did that backslash get in there? it looks like it should be `'IfNotExist\u003dtrue'` which translates to *"IfNotExist=true"*

Comment: I just added the print statement. Give it a try, maybe in https://repl.it/languages/python and you will see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from the encoding.

In fact `\u003d` is the UNICODE representation of `=`.

The backslash is escaped by another backslash which is a good thing.

You may need to:

1. Replace `\u003d` as `=`
2. Read it as unicode then you should prepend the string with `u` like `u"hi \\u003d"` may be ok

Comment: Glad it helped, consider validating the answer then to help future users :)

Answer (score 1):

When you print out your dictionary using 
`print (Configurations)`, it will print out the **repr()** value of the dictionary

You will get

`{'javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName': 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver', 'javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName': 'test', 'javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword': 'sxxxsasdsasad', 'javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL': 'jdbc:mysql://hive-metastore.cr.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist\\u003dtrue'}`

You need to print out your dictionary with 
`print (Configurations["javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL"])`

or 
`print (str(Configurations["javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL"]))`
*Note: **str()** is added*

Then the output will be

`jdbc:mysql://hive-metastore.cr.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist\u003dtrue`

For more detail check [Python Documentation - Fancier Output Formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)

> The str() function is meant to return representations of values which
>   are fairly human-readable, while repr() is meant to generate
>   representations which can be read by the interpreter (or will force a
>   SyntaxError if there is no equivalent syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Printing the dictionary shows you a representation of the dictionary object. It doesn't necessarily show you a nice representation of everything inside it. To do that you need to do:

```
for value in Configurations.values():
    print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent that string by using a single backslash instead of a double backslash, then you need the `str()` representation, not the `repr()`. When you print a dictionary, you always get the `repr()` of the included strings.

You can print the `str()` by formatting the dictionary yourself, like so:

```
print ( "{" +
    ', '.join("'{key}': '{value}'".format(key=key, value=value)
              for key, value in Configurations.items()) +
    "}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you print your string, Python will print two backslashes where the string actually only has one in it. This is Python's way of indicating that the backslash is an actual backslash, and not part of an escaped character; because print will actually show you '\n' for a carriage return, for example.

Try writing the string to a file and then opening the file in an editor.

(Linux..)

```
> f = open('/tmp/somefile.txt', 'w')
> f.write(sometextwithbackslashes)
> \d
$ vi /tmp/somefile.txt
```